# Bootstrap - label on the left side of checkbox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, bootstrap-4, label

I have a sample checkbox:

```
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
    Default checkbox
  </label>
</div>
```

I'd like to have a label on the left side. Do you know how can I do it? I tried with pull-right, but it does not work.

UPDATE:
I think the problem is with rtl class which I use in the HTML tag.

Please take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/npjm1gfy/3/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just mix them up and apply a bit of `margin`

```css
.form-check-input-reverse{
 margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-check">
<label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
    Default checkbox
  </label>
  <input class="form-check-input-reverse" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1">
</div>

<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
    Default checkbox
  </label>
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rdscbuy1/)

---

**Updated answer**

With `direction: rtl`

[**New Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/npjm1gfy/10/)

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to have the checkbox label to the right?
See below:

```
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1">
  <label class="form-check-label pull-right" for="defaultCheck1">
    Default checkbox
  </label>
</div>
```

Or
Do you want an additional label to the right of the checkbox?
See below:

```
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
    Default checkbox
  </label>
  <div class="pull-right">
    <label class="form-check-label pull-right" for="defaultCheck1">
    Pulled right label
  </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change the order visualy, you can introduce something like `.custom-checkbox-reverse`.

```css
.custom-checkbox-reverse .custom-control-label::before,
.custom-checkbox-reverse .custom-control-label::after {
    left: auto;
    right: -1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Check this custom checkbox</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-checkbox-reverse">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck2">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck2">Check this custom checkbox</label>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tive/1y8re02q/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
You can achieve with float left on label tag
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Minal4/y6xv5eas/3/

Answer (score 0):

First you have to write label and then after input tag and if there is an alignment issue put css "vertical-align:baseline"

```
<div class="form-check">
 <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
   Default checkbox
 </label>
 <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

my tricky solution, works for v5.0

```
<div class="mb-2 input-group">
  <label class="form-control m-0 p-0 border-0" for="rule-2">全面检查</label>
  <div class="input-group-text bg-transparent border-0 p-1">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="rule-2">
  </div>
</div>
```